# Is there something like std::remove() which does not preserve the order of retained elements of a vector?

Tags: c++, vector, std, stl-algorithm, unordered

In C++14, I have a `std::vector` of values for which I want to remove all elements that match a given value and I do not care about preserving the order of the elements after doing the remove.  The specification for `std::remove` provides that the relative order of the elements that remain is preserved.

Is there a built-in algorithm to do something like a `std::remove` but that does not preserve the order?  I wish to do this since it is less work to just swap elements from the end of the vector into locations to be removed, thus scrambling the order of elements in the vector.  The algorithm is still linear in that it has to visit each element to check for removal, but the amount of constant work it has to perform on each element goes way down if only a handful of items end up being removed.

Comment: The only way to do it is exactly that: by swapping elements from the end of the vector. That's how vectors work. There is no built-in C++ algorithm to do that, if that's what you're asking.

Comment: Should be pretty easy for you to write, though.

Comment: std::partition is similar to what you are looking for.

Comment: @Eugene Sounds like that fits the bill, perhaps turn your comment into an answer?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

> Is there a built-in algorithm to do something like a std::remove but that does not preserve the order? I wish to do this since it is less work to just swap elements from the end of the vector into locations to be removed

[`std::partition()`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/partition) is an algorithm that will do what you are asking for. Instead of the value to remove, you will need to provide a predicate for the values to keep.

For example, given `std::vector v;`, instead of

```
v.erase( std::remove(v.begin(), v.end(), value), v.end() );
```

you would write:

```
v.erase( std::partition(v.begin(), v.end(), [&](const auto& elem){return elem!=value;}), v.end() );
```

However, this is not necessarily more efficient than `std::remove()`. The problem is that `std::remove()` does not swap - instead, it only *moves* the elements, keeping the elements to be removed in an arbitrary moved-out state. This may be more efficient than swapping, especially if swapping vector elements is not cheap.